# Android Google ML Kit translation returning incorrect translations

Tags: android, google-translate, google-mlkit

I'm using the ML Kit translator currently with English to Polish. I know the docs say it should be used for casual words and translation, but its returning basic things like Monkey and Spark back as English words, does anyone know what could be happening?

Answer (score -1):

As you might have noticed by yourself reading the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation), this API is not intended for long and complex texts to translate. That being said if the length of your context to translate is quite long, a weird translation is just a normal output to expect.
If you require higher fidelity, you should use the [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/).
Also, I suggest you always translate to and from English because when you translate between non-English languages, the translation's quality can be poor.